# Reverse sort order in AngularJS table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I reverse `test2` based on single type (i.e age) ?

```
    $scope.test2=[{name:"abc",age:"10",gender:"m"},{name:"cde",age:"5",gender:"f"},{name:"efg",age:"25",gender:"m"},{name:"ghi",age:"15",gender:"f"}]
   // sort table by gender.
    $scope.test= $scope.test2.reverse();
```

For example if I want to sort by age then I want to reverse my whole array based on that type.

```
    $scope.test2=[{name:"cde",age:"5",gender:"f"},{name:"abc",age:"10",gender:"m"},{name:"ghi",age:"15",gender:"f"}{name:"efg",age:"25",gender:"m"},].
```

Because i am using uib-pagination and search in each col.

Comment: `$scope.test2.sort( function ( a, b ) { return a.age - b.age; });` - ascending, `$scope.test2.sort( function ( a, b ) { return b.age - a.age; });` - descending

Comment: It working for age. But will not work if i use Name field .

Comment: well any operation that yields binary result works: `$scope.test2.sort( function ( a, b ) {return a.name > b.name;});`

Comment: Thanks its working